# Unable to simplify congruence equation

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

How can I remove $x$ coefficient?
$$6x\equiv8\pmod{36}$$

$$=>\exists k,6x-8=36k$$
$$3x-4=18k$$
$$3x\equiv4\pmod{18}$$
Now if I want to remove the $x$ coefficient I will have to multiply by inverse of $3\pmod{18}$

I can't do that since inverse of $3$ doesn't exist $\pmod{18}$ and I can't do it for $4$ or $6$. So how do I approach this?

Comment: Then you have no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$3$ has order $6$ modulo $18$, and its multiple are
$$\{0,\,3,\,6,\, 9,\, 12,\, 15\}.$$
So the congruence has no solution.

Comment: If you set $x=2$, you obtain $12\equiv 8\mod 36$. Is it satisfied?

Comment: you're correct, it doesn't satisfy the equation.